# I have a serious issue with angular2 routing

Tags: jquery, angular2-routing

I'm new to angular and now I'm working with angular 2.
I have some tutorial and I'm in a progress of learning angular 2.
But my progress was stopped because of serious problem.
One of my page included jquery code, but it doesn't work when I navigate one page via routerLink.

Only the jQuery code can run by using javascript:
For example when I use the following code then all the jQuery code works without problem.
ex:

```
document.location.href="/page2";
```

`page2.html` includes `jQ.js` which contains some jQuery code.

but this is not working with jQuery functions.

```
router.navigate(['/page2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you have to use  jQuery with Angular 2.

Use Angular 2 ui-router instead!

Comment: Thanks for your messages LXhelili. Now I'm building a Web site using angular2+Laravel5. And html design was built by other. He used jQuery functions for it and I have to implement it by Angular2. That's why I have to maintain jQuery functions. Other wise I have to waste a lot of time for rebuilding Javascript functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never use Angular2 with JQuery. There are ways of doing things without JQuery and you're gonna have to learn how to do it if you really need Angular2. If you really need JQuery, then you should reconsider using Angular2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Bianca Rosa!
How can I convert html files(they are using or including jQuery functions or  import jQ.js files) to angular2.